# Xamarin.Android JARTOXML missing class error was raised while reflecting 'ClassName' : Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 18

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-proguard

Original aar lib is compiled with `API level 24` and obfuscated with latest [proguard 5.3.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/5.3/). This lib is added to the xamarin.android binding library project. Xamarin targets JDK8 in preferences `jdk1.8.0_91`.

The result is lots of warning on build like the following:

```
"missing class error was raised while reflecting "CLASS" : Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 18"
```

As a consequence, there is no generated code for that classes.
Is there any idea what could be done ?

Any help is appreciated

P.S. Without obfuscation binding generation works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jar2Xml has some specific behavior based on the JDK used:

JDK 1.7 will skip types that it decides are obfuscated. Because of this, you won't get any parser errors.

JDK 1.8 however will throw these parser errors but only for types that wouldn't be bound.

Try de-obfuscating your library via:

https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#missing-types--obfuscated-types

*Note:* Have you tried `class-parse` yet instead of Jar2Xml?

https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#pick-your-tooling

This issue was cleared up in `class-parse` recently

https://github.com/xamarin/java.interop/pull/92

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks for pointing me to the class-parse. It works perfectly.

But still, I have some questions. IS there a proper way to work with finalizers? Because I get the following error: "Do not override object.Finalize. Instead, provide a destructor." This is because generated code tries to override protected override unsafe void Finalize (), but as far as I understand, there should be JavaFinalize().

Comment: Another question is related to EnumMethods. I have such stuff in the interface and mappings works as expected. (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/#Defining_GetterSetter_Methods_using_EnumMethods.xml)

But if I have another interface which extends the first one, mappings doesn't work. I get the following error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'MyEnum'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" Is there any suggestions ?

Comment: These questions should be self contained in a new question(s) as it does not relate to the initial question.

Comment: fair enough. Thank you !